# Python requests fails on certain websites

Tags: python, http

I am using python requests to make bunch of HTTP requests to a domain. for some reason which I think pretty obvious but I don' know about, responses are coming back with `HTTP 404 Error code`.

This is where that specific URL is totally reachable using any browser(Mozilla, Chrome, etc).

Any thought on this?

Comment: to a particular domain?

Comment: Are you sending the exact same request using your Python code as using your browser? Most likely things are different (`User-Agent` for one) and those differences are what is causing the response to be different.

Comment: I meant a URL belong to a domain

Comment: @DanielPryden I tried that too, I changed the User-Agent header to exactly what chrome's request would look like. NO LUCK!

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: or at least a url that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @mehdix_: You may have changed `User-Agent`, but did you change *everything* about the request? I wouldn't be shocked if you're hitting a spam/abuse-blocking filter because it looks like you're trying to scrape a website. Check the terms and conditions of the website in question: attempting to scrape content from a site without their permission can be illegal in some jurisdictions. And the site owner is of course free to serve you any response they want, for any reason they want.

Comment: @DanielPryden I actually only tried the User-Agent and Accept headers. I guess you are right. If I'd set the exact headers, would they still be able to detect that requests coming from sources other than web browsers?

Comment: @mehdix_: There are ways. I won't go into detail here since it's a public forum and people may use the knowledge for nefarious purposes. If you really need to retrieve information from a website and normal requests via Python or curl aren't working for you, you should contact the website owner and ask how they would prefer you retrieve the information you need.